# Debugging Website on Blackberry Bold 9900

Tags: css, blackberry

I've come across a strange issue with a website when viewed on a BB Bold 9900 OS version 7.0.0
I'm sure it's just a css issue but I've been trying for days to rectify to no avail.

It's just a black line that is appearing on the site between 2 divs.

Strange thing is the website renders perfectly across all major browsers including an older BB curve and Iphone.

If anyone has a solution for debugging on this specific device I'd greatly appreciate it. I run on a Mac so the emulators are out of the question and I don't have access to this specific device.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use Web Inspector to connect to the device, while browsing to the page. Then use the mouse to highlight elements in the HTML tab and turning/adding styles on the fly to see what's causing the black line.

For more information on Web Inspector, go to https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_webinsp_microsite_1987477_11.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Web Inspector is a great tool, I use it all the time during web development. Unfortunately I don't have the offending  BB handy to try it out. Will definitely try this once I get my hands on one.